# Name for introducing negation with quantifiers

Tags: logic, terminology

The rewriting of $\varphi\to \psi$ into the logically equivalent $\neg \psi\to\neg \varphi$ is called *contraposition*.

Is there a similar word for rewriting $\forall x.\varphi$ into $\neg\exists x.\neg \varphi$?

The two operations are similar in that they replace one logical construction with one in which the subformulas of the original appear negated instead.

---

*Background:* I came across this when I noticed that the set-theoretic Axiom of Regularity seems much more intuitive and motivated if instead of the usual formulation

> **R.** Every nonempty set $A$ has an element that is disjoint from $A$.

one thinks of it as

> **R'.** There is no nonempty set $A$ such that every element of $A$ has an element that is itself in $A$.

(The set that R' claims doesn't exist would be an in-universe witness of one or more infinitely descending $\in$-chains (at least if Dependent Choice holds at the metalevel)).

But then I discovered that I don't have a nice succinct way to describe the rewriting that got me from R to R'.

Comment: To me the rewriting here is very different.  Contraposition still have the "→" connective around.  The other rewriting allows you to eliminate universal qunatifiers if you want to (it's a possible definition of universal quantification in a system which only has existential quantification at it's basis).  Also, I think you mean that the proper subformulas of the original have gotten negated, since the subformula (¬ψ→¬φ) is not negated.  Examples of all subformulas getting replaced by their negations is Kpq by NANpNq and Apq by NKNpNq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a similar word for rewriting ∀x.φ into ¬∃x.¬φ?

Short answer: No.

Or at least there surely isn't one in common usage.

Making that kind of move in a proof in a lecture, I would probably have just said "By [the familiar] quantifier equivalence, ..."

By the way, the observation that Regularity is more intuitively appealing in the version $\mathbf{R}'$ is surely exactly right (I think some of the intro set books make the same point, but it is certainly a point worth making!).

Answer (score 1):

*Contraposition* in *classical* logic can be "reduced" to the *equivalence* between :

> $p \rightarrow q$ and $\lnot p \lor q$.

Thus, from :

> $\varphi \rightarrow \psi$

using *Commutativity* : $(\lnot \varphi \lor \psi) \leftrightarrow (\psi \lor \lnot \varphi)$, and *Double Negation* we get :

> $\lnot \psi \rightarrow \lnot \varphi$.

---

For the quantifiers, we can exploit the "analogy" between $\forall$ and an infinite *conjunction* and $\exists$ and an infinite *disjunction*.

Thus, starting from the correspondance between :

> $\forall x \varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(x_1) \land \varphi(x_2) \land \ldots$

and applying a sort of "infinite" *De Morgan*, we have that :

> $\lnot \forall x \varphi(x)$ correspond to : $\lnot \varphi(x_1) \lor \lnot \varphi(x_2) \lor \ldots$

which again can be read as : $\exists x \lnot \varphi(x)$.

---

*Thus, if we want to "baptize" it, I think that "De Morgan" is more appropriate than "Contraposition"*.

---

---

*Note*

We have to note that all three *equivalences* used :

> $(p \rightarrow q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor q)$
>
> $\lnot \lnot p \leftrightarrow p$
>
> $\lnot (p \land q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor \lnot q)$

hold only in *classical* logic.

Answer (score 0):

Since the universal quantifier in $\varphi$ is equivalent to a conjunction of $[\overline{a}/x]\varphi$ of all elements $a$ of the universe $U$ (and the same holds for the existential quantifier in terms of disjunctions), they are regarded to be generalizations of De Morgan's laws, as others answered already:

$$\begin{align} \neg \forall x (\varphi) & \equiv \neg \bigwedge_{ a \in U} [\overline{a}/x]\varphi \tag{1} \\
&\equiv \bigvee_{a \in U} [\overline{a}/x]\neg\varphi   \tag{2}  \\
&\equiv \exists  x \neg (\varphi) \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

---

About your observation on the Axiom of Regularity in Set theory, I would say I myself experience the same phenomenon about the **Compactness Theorem**:

> $Γ$ has a model ⇔ each finite subset $Δ$ of $Γ$ has a model.

Particularly, I feel that ($\Leftarrow$) sounds counter intuitive, when in its contrapositive form

> $Γ$ has no model ⇒ Some finite subset $Δ$ of $Γ$ has no model.

it seems more transparent.

Comment: ... especially when one remembers that "has no model" is equivalent to "can prove a contradiction", thanks to Gödel.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Fully agree!